# Not getting the WM_DPICHANGED notification

Tags: c, winapi, dpi, multiple-monitors

I have a Win32 application where I have implemented a `groupWndProc()` callback and I'm getting the notifications except for `WM_DPICHANGED`.

I have two monitors connected: one regular and one 4k. I expect to get the notification when moving the application from one monitor to another.

Comment: do you run on win8.1 or newer?

Comment: I run it on windows 10

Comment: In what header WM_DPICHENGED defined? Couldn't find the answer on MSDN

Comment: does `GetDpiForMonitor` return different dpis for your monitors?

Comment: @BeyelerStudios What .dll exposes it?

Comment: I believe you won't get it unless your manifest marks your program as per-monitor DPI aware.

Comment: Check the High DPI Reference on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh447398(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @JonathanPotter maybe you can set it via `SetProcessDpiAwareness`?

Comment: @BeyelerStudios Possibly, I've never looked at DPI stuff myself.

Comment: @BeyelerStudios I've set it via `SetProcessDpiAwareness`

Comment: you'll have to set the process dpi awareness before any window creation and it should work, otherwise you're left with the manifest option

Comment: @Sanich Please don't make us guess at the value of your process dpi awareness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your process is DPI aware using `SetProcessDpiAwareness` with `Process_Per_Monitor_DPI_Aware` and according to [the tutorial on msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd464659(v=vs.85).aspx) you must call this before creating your windows. Make sure your monitors when queried return different dpis using `GetDpiForMonitor`.

For reference check the [High DPI Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh447398(v=vs.85).aspx).

Alternatively setup an application manifest as [per this tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn469266(v=vs.85).aspx#declaring_dpi_awareness). Add a `dpiAware` element to your application manifest:

```
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3" >
  <asmv3:application>
    <asmv3:windowsSettings xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">
      <dpiAware>True/PM</dpiAware>
    </asmv3:windowsSettings>
  </asmv3:application>
</assembly>
```

and make sure your compiler includes the manifest: add the manifest file to Project properties -> Configuration properties -> Manifest Tool -> Additional Manifest Files.